# php code sniffer codeigniter error - "CodeIgniter.Files.ClosingLocationComment" does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpcodesniffer

I spent whole day installing pear, code sniffer on my mac El Capitan. I also installed codeigniter sniff from this link [Sniffs for codeigniter](https://github.com/thomas-ernest/CodeIgniter-for-PHP_CodeSniffer)
and followed this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MazpKcAVD74).
  Now when I test my codeigniter code I get below error

```
amits-iMac:~ amitpatil$ phpcs --standard=Codeignitor /Applications/AMPPS/www/project/front/application/controllers/about.php

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHP_CodeSniffer_Exception' with message 'Referenced sniff "CodeIgniter.Files.ClosingLocationComment" does not exist' in /Users/amitpatil/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:1144
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/amitpatil/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer.php(757): PHP_CodeSniffer->_expandRulesetReference(Object(SimpleXMLElement), '/Users/amitpati...', 0)
#1 /Users/amitpatil/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer.php(561): PHP_CodeSniffer->processRuleset('/Users/amitpati...')
#2 /Users/amitpatil/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(870): PHP_CodeSniffer->initStandard(Array, Array)
#3 /Users/amitpatil/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(106): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->process()
#4 /usr/local/bin/phpcs(25): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->runphpcs()
#5 {main}
thrown in /Users/amitpatil/pear/share/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 1144
```

Answer (score 0):

That repo looks pretty old, and it wont work with any PHP_CodeSniffer version that I have tried. But the fix is relatively simple. The `src` directory just needs to be renamed:

```
$ cd CodeIgniter-for-PHP_CodeSniffer
$ mv src CodeIgniter
```

Now it should work by running the command:
`phpcs --standard=/path/to/CodeIgniter-for-PHP_CodeSniffer/CodeIgniter /path/to/code`

Comment: Greg, I have done that, I did renamed that folder to "Codeignitor" and moved inside "Standards" folder, which is inside "Codesniffer" folder.

Comment: You don't need to move the folder into the CodeSniffer/Standards directory - obviously old instructions. I just cloned the repo, renamed the dir, and used the standard directly. Works fine. If you really want to install it, you're better off using the installed_paths config var these days: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Configuration-Options#setting-the-installed-standard-paths